# Can I add an image to a d3js graph?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

Is it possible to add an image in the bottom right corner of my bar chart? I want to look something like this graph

[image: graph.jpg]

This is the link to the image I want to add.https://postimg.org/image/3zrzf3vpr/ Do I need to resize it before I connect it or can I do this within the code?

Here is my Plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/sekJlYevx2dw28zLuC4d?p=preview

I assumed I could add it similar to how I add text using what I have below. Though if these is a better way to do it without basing it off the xaxis that would be fantastic.

```
svg.append("g")
  .attr("class", "x axis")
  .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
  .call(xAxis)
  .append("text")
  .attr("class", "label")
  .attr("x", 170)
  .attr("y", 40)
  .style("text-anchor", "end")
  .text("Source: D.C. Open Data, D.C. Policy Center");
```

but I'm having a hard time figuring out the exact way to do it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Putting the image in a separate element is one approach.

The better approach in my opinion is to have it inside your SVG. You can append it like the following and position it accordingly. I used the following to add it to your plunkr:

```
  var imgs = svg
        .append("svg:image")
        .attr("xlink:href", "https://s27.postimg.org/h3xjrsnrn/dcpolicycenter.png")
            .attr("x", width - 100)
            .attr("y", height - 14)
            .attr("width", "100")
            .attr("height", "100");
```

I've updated your Plunkr. Please check here -> http://plnkr.co/edit/hNZXJaKGwTu9Ps4VlhfJ?p=preview

Comment: This is excellent! Thanks so much! I never would have figured this out without the help.

Answer (score 0):

You can just put the image (a separate element from the graph) below the graph, set the position of the image as absolute, and adjust its attributes (e.g. top, left) so that it goes where you want it to.